# How to get corresponding id with minimum value of a row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named `deals` and `mp_details`. Columns `deal_id` and `mp_details_id` are the two primary keys. There is a relation between the two tables using the `deal_mp_id` column where it works as a foreign key. I want to fetch all the minimum records of column name `deal_selling_price` with group by `mp_details_id`.  Here are the tables:

**deals**

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ deal_id ║ deal_mp_id ║ deal_selling_price ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬════════════════════╣
║    3    ║     1      ║        425         ║
║    4    ║     1      ║        540         ║  
║    5    ║     2      ║        340         ║
║    6    ║     2      ║        315         ║
║    7    ║     3      ║        425         ║
║    8    ║     3      ║        720         ║
║    9    ║     4      ║        382.5       ║
║   10    ║     4      ║        495         ║
║   11    ║     5      ║        595         ║
║   12    ║     5      ║        720         ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

**mp_details**

```
╔═══════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ mp_details_id ║   mp_details_name   ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║       1       ║ Olive Bar & Kitchen ║
║       2       ║ Thai High           ║
║       3       ║ Tonino              ║
║       4       ║ Impromptu           ║
║       5       ║ Zerruco             ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

**And I want this kind of result:**

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ deal_id ║ deal_mp_id ║ deal_selling_price ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬════════════════════╣
║    3    ║     1      ║        425         ║
║    6    ║     2      ║        315         ║
║    7    ║     3      ║        425         ║
║    9    ║     4      ║        382.5       ║
║   11    ║     5      ║        595         ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

Comment: What is your query? what do you mean by `"minimum records"`? what output you expected?

Comment: MIN(deal_selling_price)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will give you the result set from your screen capture above:

```
SELECT d1.deal_id, d1.deal_mp_id, d2.minPrice
FROM deals d1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT deal_mp_id, MIN(deal_selling_price) AS minPrice
    FROM deals
    GROUP BY deal_mp_id
) d2
    ON d1.deal_mp_id = d2.deal_mp_id AND d1.deal_selling_price = d2.minPrice
```

If you *also* want to include information from the `mp_details` table, you can do an additional join like this:

```
SELECT d1.deal_id, d1.deal_mp_id, d2.minPrice, mp.mp_details_name
FROM deals d1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT deal_mp_id, MIN(deal_selling_price) AS minPrice
    FROM deals
    GROUP BY deal_mp_id
) d2
    ON d1.deal_mp_id = d2.deal_mp_id AND d1.deal_selling_price = d2.minPrice
INNER JOIN mp_details mp
    ON d1.deal_mp_id = mp.mp_details_id
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/769383/4)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
select 
    D.Deal_id, MD.mp_details_id, MIN(D.deal_selling_price) 
FROM
    deals D inner join  mp_details MD 
ON
    D.Deal_id = MD.mp_details_id 
GROUP BY 
   D.Deal_id, MD.mp_details_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT d.deal_id, d.deal_mp_id, d.deal_selling_price
FROM deals d
JOIN
(
  SELECT deal_mp_id, MIN(deal_selling_price) AS min_selling_price
  FROM deals
  GROUP BY deal_mp_id
) m
ON d.deal_mp_id = m.deal_mp_id AND d.deal_selling_price = m.min_selling_price
```

Comment: one minute..let me check